# Android Dropdown-Menu (No spinner!)

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-listview, android-spinner

I want to create a dropdown navigation. I drew this sketch:

[image]

I already tried a spinner, but I don't want that combobox, only that list, which shows on the button click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are working on an API below 11. The Dropdown spinner is available from API Level 11 with the Actionbar. **But** you could use Actionbar sherlock. Download the Demos( as source from Github or as an app from the play store). The actionbarsherlock implements dropdownspinners. It should look like this:

[image]

You can get the Library from:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Thank you! The sub-menu sample is exatly what i need.

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at the example of ApiDemos->Views->popup menu. This may be appropriate. If not, I am afraid, you may have to make custom UI for this one.

Comment: What API-Version do i need for this example?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a `Dialog` and inflate its view from an xml layout.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
dialog.show();
```